# How to use OpenMP with recursive

Tags: c++, openmp

I wanted to ask if is it possible somehow to use openmp in my code.

```
class Triangle {
public:
    void drawLine(Point from, Point to) {
        //Do something.
    }

    void drawTriangle(Point a, Point b, Point c, Triangle triangle, int level) {
        if (level == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Point ab = Point((a.x + b.x) / 2, (a.y + b.y) / 2);
        Point bc = Point((b.x + c.x) / 2, (b.y + c.y) / 2);
        Point ca = Point((c.x + a.x) / 2, (c.y + a.y) / 2);

        //Is it possible to use Open MP here?
        triangle.drawLine(a, b);
        triangle.drawLine(b, c);
        triangle.drawLine(a, c);

        //Is it possible to use open MP here too?
        drawTriangle(a, ab, ca, triangle, level - 1);
        drawTriangle(ab, b, bc, triangle, level - 1);
        drawTriangle(ca, bc, c, triangle, level - 1);
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int amountOfPowers = 2
    int level =3
    Point a = Point(pow(2, amountOfPowers), 0);
    Point b = Point(pow(2, amountOfPowers), pow(2, amountOfPowers));
    Point c = Point(pow(2, amountOfPowers) - (pow(2, amountOfPowers) * sqrt(3.0) / 2), pow(2, amountOfPowers) / 2);

    Triangle triangle = Triangle();
    triangle.drawTriangle(a, b, c, triangle, level);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use OpenMP inside drawTraingle method. Is it possible in any way to use it here? Because I wanted to make 3xtriangle.drawLine() method in one time (use OpenMP on it) and also (if it's possible) later 3xdrawTriangle method in one time.

@edit

I tried something like it, is it correct?

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
#pragma omp single nowait
        {
#pragma omp task 
            triangle.drawLine(a, b);
#pragma omp task 
            triangle.drawLine(copyB, c);
#pragma omp task 
            triangle.drawLine(copyA, copyC);
        }
```

Comment: Is it correct what I wrote in edited post?

Comment: When I run this code (with #pragma omp task) I don't have any errors but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

For something so simple and little it's better to do it with the sequential form than parallele solution. You only draw three line. OpenMP use preprocessor directives that will create exacly a pthread. Creating a thread take time and finishing it too. So your parallele solution will be less efficient than your sequentiel code.

If you had loops with 1000 iteration and greater, it will be a good choice to use OpenMP, but in your situation it's a bad idea. In this situation an OpenCL solution will be a good idea, because your situation need to use the graphic card performance than the processor, but even with OpenCL, I think it will be not fast enought at the begining beacuase your code is realy small. And if you dont have a graphic card OpenCL will use your processor and it will take the same time than OpenMP. Moreover OpenCL need some intialization that will take too many time at the begining, and your sequential code will be finished at the time that OpenCL solution will begin to process the your code.

If you want to learn OpenMP, you need to find a situation that need to be parallelized and think about if the parallelized solution will be faster or less fast. You cannot parallelize every solution, sometimes sequential solutions is better and you don't need to parallelize them.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use OpenCL but my school task is to use OpenMP here :/

Comment: So it means that your situation is more complex than your code, I think your school task should be a parallelizable situation and you need to review if you undertood it correctly